# Connecting to database.mdf after installation on target computer

Tags: vb.net

I have this problem stated in the title. It keeps saying:

> A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider:SQL Network interfaces, error:26- Error Locating Server/ instance specified)".

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

I used vb.net so what shall I do to fix this?

Comment: You need to install the database product on client machine.

Comment: Are you trying to open a SQL Server `mdf` as if it was an Access `mdb`?

Comment: Is SQL Server **Express** installed on the target machine?

Answer (score 0):

I think the AppData folder doesn't get copied or mdf files are not getting copied when deploying to IIS.

Check whether property of the mdf file is Copy Always or Copy if newer is set

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add the **Database Name** to the connection string. The correct connection string should be like this.

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB); AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf; InitialCatalog=DatabaseName; Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: first of all my database name is "Database1.mdf" and it is already in the target computer after installing the executable. and as my friend here SAMi said i changed the connection string name and compiled again but i'm getting the error that says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'initialcatalog'." did i get your idea SAMi? or are you saying that i shall change the constring in the target computer on file "App.config"

Comment: Mahesh Malpani it is set to Copy always. thank you guys by the way

Comment: my app.config file looks like this <?xml version="1.0"           encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration> <configSections>                       </configSections> <connectionStrings> <add name="HuaweiSoft.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>       <startup> <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> </startup>     </configuration>

Comment: Please change the InitialCatalog into 2 words, "Initial Catalog"

Comment: you can see that there is no command related to initial catalog on the connection string. i'm wondering how people deploy service-based database on target machines. how can i upload it so you guys can see it your self. i'm really pissed of this thing... it took me almost a week... still nothing. ..and thanx btw